# Automatic input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to make automatic input on click based on two pare of images.
On the left side I have 2 images that need to be connect with two input fields, and on the right side also have two images with letter that should be field in that input. So if I click on image 1, then the input 1 will be field with letter that is connect with image on the right side.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
        $('.inputs').val($(this).data('letter'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
         <div id="old" class="left_side one_half">
          <a href="#" data-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a href="#" data-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_side one_half">
          <a href="#" data-letter="EI"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a href="#" data-letter="AL"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
        </div>
<div class="answer_1">
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
```

With this solution, I can only fill in al fields with all letters, and can not connect only first field with desired letter.
Hope that I explain this right. Thanks.

Comment: Where are the input fields in this example?

Comment: I don't see any input elements. Do you mean anchor tags?

Comment: Please include your input tag, and explain what you expected result are, that way we will get a much better understanding of what you wish to get.

Comment: Sorry, I missed input field. I want that when you click on image one, input one to be field with data-letter of another image that is clicked, and when I click on image two, then input two to be field with data-letter of another image (one that user choose).

Comment: @MarkoPetković so what you want is, when click on first image, fill first input, click on second image, fill second input?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes. You click on images that are under id=old data-number="1" and first input be field depend on what is second image that you clicked (this one that have data-letter). If you clicked on image data-number="1" and image data-letter="EI", then first is field with EI, and if you clicke on data-number="1" and data-letter="AL", then first field is field with AL.

Comment: @MarkoPetković check my answer below . if you want clarifications don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i understood what you want.

In the below example you will see that the selected input ( depending on the data-number of the clicked `#old a` )  will get a blue background. Then when clicking on the second column of images ( with data-letter ) , the previously selected input ( with blue background) will get value the data-letter of the clicked image

Images from the `old` column are faded with opacity so you can see which is which.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for

```js
var input = $(".inputs")
$('#old a').click(function() {
  var nr = $(this).attr("data-number"),
  letterA = $(this).parent("#old").siblings(".left_side").find("a")
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected").val("")
  $(input).eq(nr - 1).addClass("selected")

 

  $(letterA).on("click", function() {
    var letter = $(this).attr("data-letter")

    $(".selected").val(letter)

  });
});
```

```css
.left_side {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.selected {
  background: blue;
}

input {
  color: red
}

#old img {
  opacity: 0.5
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div id="old" class="left_side one_half">
    <a href="#" data-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="left_side one_half">
    <a href="#" data-letter="EI"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="AL"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="answer_1">
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
```

Comment: @MarkoPetković glad i could help. Don't forget to upvote/accept my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
$('a.left_a').click(function(){
    var a_id = $(this).data('number');
    $('#input_'+a_id).val($('#right_'+a_id).data('letter'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
         <div id="old" class="left_side one_half">
          <a class="left_a" href="javascript:void(0);" data-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a class="left_a" href="javascript:void(0);" data-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_side one_half">
          <a id="right_1" href="javascript:void(0);" data-letter="EI"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a id="right_2" href="javascript:void(0);" data-letter="AL"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
        </div>
<div class="answer_1">
  <input id="input_1" class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
  <input id="input_2" class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the index of the clicked element from the `parent` using [`index()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj86fDzyKbVAhVFHpQKHduZDbQQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Findex%2F&usg=AFQjCNENMYfGKQCoUjBO94uh61WjLwcvyQ) function .so change the selector with `parent with childelement` .
2. And select the respected input element using [`eq()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiEqI_myKbVAhULpZQKHSD5BPAQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Feq%2F&usg=AFQjCNF421AWRe2A4OnKM21N9XQV5cUFMA) function

```js
$('.left_side a[data-letter]').click(function(){
console.log('s')
  var a = $(this).index()
        $('.answer_1 .inputs').eq(a).val($(this).data('letter'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
         <div id="old" class="left_side one_half">
          <a href="#" data-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a href="#" data-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_side one_half">
          <a href="#" data-letter="EI"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a href="#" data-letter="AL"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
        </div>
<div class="answer_1">
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
```

Comment: This solution is not good, because it can not fill field one with data-letter from both of images.

Comment: now it only target data-letter attr contain element

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Change the `class name` for second div to `right_side` `<div class="right_side one_half">`

**2nd :** you can use `index()` to find the clicked element is `first` or `second` . based on that `index()` select the `data-letter` from right side image .using `eq(a)`.

```js
$('.left_side a').click(function(){
  var a = $(this).index()
        $('.inputs').eq(a).val($('.right_side a').eq(a).data('letter'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
         <div id="old" class="left_side one_half">
          <a href="#" data-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a href="#" data-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="right_side one_half">
          <a href="#" data-letter="EI"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
          <a href="#" data-letter="AL"><img data-letter="EI" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
         </div>
        </div>
<div class="answer_1">
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
  <input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> i cant understand what you are trying  as per my assumption i think
>   when click on first image read data-number then put it in first input
>   and when click on second image data-letter then put it on the second
>   input this is my assumption please check below if it is what you are
>   trying to say

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {  
   return this.attr(name) !== undefined;
};  // create a function hasAttr

$(document).ready(function() {

      $('a').click(function(){
          if($(this).hasAttr('data-number')){
              $('#input_left ').val($(this).attr('data-number'));
         }else if($(this).hasAttr('data-letter'){
         $('#input_right').val($(this).attr('data-letter'));
        }
    });
});
```

In your html :

```
<input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" id="input_left" />
<input class="inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text" id="input_right" />
```